# Configure a Google Analytics filter for blog posts when URLs are mixed with other content

Tags: google-analytics, wordpress, blog, traffic, filtering

I have a WordPress site with a blog section but also a lot of other content, that is not directly related to the blog. Now I want to use Google Analytics and only see the blog traffic, meaning users that click on blog posts.

I know there are ways to filter this, if the blog posts reside in a subfolder, like `example.com/blog/my-blog-post`, but on my site the link structure doesn't have that. It's like this: `example.com/my-blog-post`

What would be a good way to filter that traffic in Google Analytics? It should also work for any future published posts. I have the Google Tag Manager connected, maybe that might provide a viable option?

Comment: Is there any distinguishing feature of the blog posts at all, such as something in their page title? Do you already have GA running, or is this a question about creating the analytics setup?

Answer (score 1):

Filtering traffic at the View level can only be done based on four specific options, either sources or destinations:

- Source Traffic by IP
- Source Traffic by ISP
- Destination By Hostname
- Destination By Subdirectory

As such, you couldn't filter out only the blog traffic to your website unless your blogs were all in a subdirectory.

Using Advanced Filters while actually browsing the data gives you a lot more options and these can be stored and recovered using saved reports. Depending on how your blogs are identified, you could filter the data by the pages' URIs or Titles.

Unfortunately, without a nice catchall way of defining your blogs, it will be tricky for you to ensure you get them all. It might be simpler, depending on the number of pages on your site which aren't blog pages to simply exclude them.

Comment: Thank you! I used the Google Tag Manager to create a custom variable now. Since blog posts have the post type "post", instead of "page" in WordPress, they can be distinguished by that. However, it requires to set this up in the Google Tag Manager. In Google Analytics I have then the dimension "post type" which I can use to filter. This only works for any future traffic, however, since the variable hasn't been tracked in the past ofc, which makes this only a partial solution. But it works for me. I might post this in more detail as an answer, if I have the time.